# Using generating function to find number of different election results when there is no majority.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

My question is as follows:

(a) Use a generating function for modeling the number of different election outcomes in an election for class president if 25 students are voting among four candidates. Which coefficient do we want?

(b) Suppose each student who is a candidate votes for herself or himself. Now what is the generating function and the required coefficient?

(c) Suppose no candidate receives a majority of the vote. Repeat part (a).

I found the first two parts relatively easy, and got answers of $(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{25})^4$, looking for the coefficient of $x^{25}$ and $(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{21})^4$, looking for the coefficient of $x^{21}$ respectively.

However I am having trouble with part c). My logic and attempt is as follows:

A majority of 25 is 13, so in order to prevent this, each candidate will have 12 or less votes, making the generating function:

$$(1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{12})^4$$

and we would be looking for the coefficient of $x^{25}$ again to find the answer.

Is this correct, or am I missing something here? Thanks.

Comment: Where did these questions come from? Seems like it could be an good book for me to add to my reading list

Comment: @frogeyedpeas It's from Applied Combinatorics by Alan Tucker, I believe it's the 6th edition.

Comment: Just looking at the book (and taking into account the simplicity of chapter 6) it seems to me that question 8 (c) means *exactly what you suggest*. "Majority of the vote" means *exactly that* and not "more votes than any other candidate" which would be a significantly more difficult question. This then wouldn't fit with the difficulty of the rest of the questions and I'm not even sure there is an easy way to do it with generating functions. So I'd go with what you have.

Comment: According in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurality_(voting)), at least in American English, _majority_ means more than half the votes.  Meanwhile, "more votes than any other candidates" is instead called _plurality_.